# Correct oven temperature for chicken tikka at home

Tags: chicken, oven, indian-cuisine

To make chicken tikka in oven, should I bake at 350c for about 40 min and then broil it on high for 2 min? 
I don't expect same taste as if it was a tandoor oven, but hoping for something close.

Assume I have the ingredients for proper marinade?

Comment: are you sure it is 350C? I usually do it at 180C. Also as chicken releases water i make sure i change the sides of tikka so they cook evenly. How do you place your tikka in oven? In a baking tray or just on the bars of the shelves in oven?

Comment: Thank you. On skewers on top of a tray. How long do you bake at 180c?

Comment: It takes me about an hour , it could take less if you have only few skewers. I changed sides every 15 minutes because unlike tandoor our owens do not heat equally from all sides. Take one piece out from any skewer to see if the meat inside is cooked or not after about 30 mins. also if it starts drying up apply bit butter on skewers with brush or spray, it will taste great too.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that the tikkas do not touch a surface e.g. an aluminium foil or a tray. Suspend them from a grid and use a lined tray at the bottom of the oven to collect the fat/juices. Cook at 180°C for 20-25 minutes (to cook the chicken through) and then cook on maximum temperature (usually 350°C) for 5-7 minutes to get the charred/burnt effect.

As a side note, roast some besan (gram flour) and ajwain (carom seeds) in 1 tablespoon of mustard oil and add it to the marinade. And sprinkle coriander and mint extremely finely chopped together over your chicken immediately after it is out of the oven.

For the best tikkas or tandoori, if you have the time and space, build and use your own tandoor as described here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Ukb_WoUG2Q

Comment: why should it not touch the surface?

Comment: Because then it will not roast, it will cook in it's own juices like a curry.

Comment: That marinade sounds like what Harpal Singh uses ... tried it it is awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

350C is very high temperature for tikkas, use a 180C oven. First you need to boil the chicken for 5 to 10 minutes on medium heat, then put the chicken in marinade ingredients, and after 10 minutes, put it in the oven. It’ll take 20 minutes to cook.

Comment: Chicken for tikka/tandoori is not boiled in the original recipe as it will give out all the juices when boiled and will get a rubbery/dry texture when roasted in a closed oven/tandoor.

Answer (score 0):

Use chicken tenders.  marinade minimum 4 hours in a mixture of ginger and garlic paste, yogurt, a little olive olive, Dhaniya powder, salt, Kasuri Methi, Kashmiri Mirch.  Heat own to 500F. place tenders in skewer and place skewer on a deep dish so chicken is 'hanging' If oven has convection feature use convection bake,  Let tenders cook for 17-20 minutes,  Check that inside cooked temp is 165F.  Let rest for 5 minutes, place in bowl. Brush/drizzle with ghee, sprinkle with chopped coriander. Toss.

Comment: "a little olive olive"? Did you mean "a little olive oil"?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the oven at all. Your method will just result in completely over-done chicken. Chicken breast is very low fat & has little to no collagen. Therefore it's cooked to perfection as soon as it reaches the right internal temperature. Two minutes more & it turns to pencil erasers; four minutes & it's dry… for which there is no real fix.

If you're cooking chicken breast in bite-sized chunks you need around 4-6 minutes on a grill/broiler, as hot & close as you can get it. Domestic cookers can't get anywhere near the temperature or heat concentration of a tandoor.

Flip just as the first side shows initial charring, the second side will be quicker.

As you're making up the skewers, put one or two of the largest pieces nearest to you so you can reach them without having to take the whole skewer out, as sacrificial test pieces. Break one with a fork when the outside is just slightly charring at the extremities on your second side. If your sacrificial piece is done [no pink, no runny, no 'jellied' appearance], so are the rest.

Serve immediately.